# Not able to add a column to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I have a table named `T_Bibliotheque`. I need to add a column so I tried with the design mode and with the following command :

```
ALTER TABLE T_bibliotheque 
    ADD documentElectronique INT
```

I keep receiving the following error message.

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal,
>   Line 75
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks,

Samuel

Comment: Are you doing this in a Fresh query? (NEW QUERY)


It looks like you're getting extra SQL syntax in your execute. Can you try highlighting everything from `ALTER TABLE` to `INT` and then hit EXECUTE?

Comment: Line 75? I think we are missing a bit of the code here. Does the preceding statement in your code end with a semicolon?

Comment: I bet line 75 of that procedure has a `SELECT * FROM T_bibliotheque UNION ... `

Comment: Sorry guys, I just found what the problem was. The table was referenced in a View, but the view didn't replaced the * with the column names in the SELECT * FROM TABLE.

However, I don't know why it didn't replace...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just found what the problem was. The table was referenced in a view, but the view didn't replace the `*` with the column names in the `SELECT * FROM TABLE`.

However, I don't know why it didn't replace...